# cannot change image in datagridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, image, datagridview

i need to change the image of the column if a path specified in another column exists.

i have the following code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;


        DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        buttonCol.HeaderText = "";
        buttonCol.Name = "BrowseButton";
        buttonCol.Text = "...";
        buttonCol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; 
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonCol);

        DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        imgCol.HeaderText = "Status";
        imgCol.Name = "StatusImage";
        imgCol.Image = null;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgCol);
        dataGridView1.Columns["StatusImage"].DisplayIndex = 4;

 foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string overRiddenDirPath = myRow.Cells["Overridden Dir"].Value.ToString();
            string preConfiguredPath = myRow.Cells["PreConfigured Dir"].Value.ToString();
            string path = overRiddenDirPath;
            if (overRiddenDirPath == "")
            {
                path = preConfiguredPath;
            }

            DataGridViewImageCell cell = myRow.Cells["StatusImage"] as DataGridViewImageCell;

            // If the directory doesn't exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                cell.Value = Image.FromFile(@"Chrysanthemum.jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Value = Image.FromFile(@"Jellyfish.jpg");                   
            }
        }
```

no image is getting displayed: 
the path of the image is fine because if i put it like this :

```
  DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        imgCol.HeaderText = "Status";
        imgCol.Name = "StatusImage";
        imgCol.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Chrysanthemum.jpg");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgCol);
        dataGridView1.Columns["StatusImage"].DisplayIndex = 4;
```

it gets displayed but it does not change on the condition.

Also, is there a better way to add images to a datagridview cells.

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Did you try calling EndEdit and Refresh on grid and parent control? I won't bet that's the problem, but it may help.

Comment: so i think you are right... when i call just the condition function from a textchange function it changes the image. this means the code is correct. its just not refreshing after getting the values...

Comment: can u tell me how do i refresh from a function and what is EndEdit..

Comment: About EndEdit() you can read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620.aspx. dataGridView1.Refresh() - call after all changes are done.

Comment: the dataGridView1.Refresh() does not do anything??

Comment: and how would i put EndEdit in above. i could not figure it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your code in the `CellFormatting` event instead.

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{            
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "StatusImage")
    {
        // Your code would go here - below is just the code I used to test
        e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\TestImage.jpg");
    }
}
```

The one important thing to note is that you set e.Value rather than cell.Value here.

---

Here is the code from an example I tried where I access the value of another column to conditionally change the selected image. This works perfectly regardless of which display index the image has.

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "StatusImage")
        {
            if (((int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ValueTwo"].Value) == 5)
            {
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\TestImage1.jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\TestImage2.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example I have a column with integer values within it, but it should work for text in a similar fashion.

Comment: as you can see from my code above i need to get the value of another cell in the same row and if that value is true then display images accordingly. I tried applying your code but am unable to get the value of the other cell at the same time as the value of the image col.

Comment: @user175084 what fails? do you get an exception of any kind? I just tried putting some conditional logic within the CellFormatting event to change the image and it worked perfectly.

Comment: hey.. can you show me an example of what you did.. the cell formatting gets one cell at a time. i need to get values of 2 other cells present in the same row compare which is greater and display an image accordingly..

Comment: @user175084 have a look at my latest edit. I'm not doing anything special - it all just works for me. Do you get any errors when you try this or have you got any other unusual code that might change things?