# DataGridViewImageColumn don't display the value - why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datagridcolumn

I want to display some images in my dataGridView, so I created `DataGridViewImageColumn` with default image (`Properties.Resources.test`), added it to `dataGridView` and tried to insert some values to cells. Unfortunately it didn't change the display. What Am I doing wrong?

```
        var q = from a in _dc.GetTable<Map>() select a;
        View.dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
        View.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;

        var imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn
        {
            Image = Properties.Resources.test,
            ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch,
            Name = "Map",
            HeaderText = @"map"
        };
        View.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var map in q)
        {
            View.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = ByteArrayToImage(map.map1.ToArray());
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot change image in datagridview winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473310/cannot-change-image-in-datagridview-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the question in the comment you need to use the CellFormatting event like so:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{             
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "StatusImage") 
    { 
        // Your code would go here - below is just the code I used to test 
        e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\TestImage.jpg"); 
    } 
}
```

So set e.Value rather than cell.Value and assign the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...

```
 for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i ++)
            if(dataGridView1.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn) {
                ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
                break;
            }
```